# ¿Por que se suma dos veces el resultado al usar SUM () con JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, sqlite, mysqldb

Hola tengo la siguiente pregunta y es que la suma se duplica y no se por que,suma dos veces el resultado al usar `SUM()` con JOIN en Mysql. Cada resultado sale el doble en `INVERSION_VALOR` sale 492 en ves de 246,en `INVERSION_VALOR` sale 20246 en ves de 10123

```
SELECT I.FECHA      AS INV_FECHA,
       SUM(I.VALOR) AS INVERSION_VALOR, 
       SUM(G.VALOR) AS GASTO_VALOR 
       FROM INVERSION AS I 
       INNER JOIN GASTOS AS G ON I.FECHA = G.FECHA 
       GROUP BY(I.FECHA)`
```

Comment: Me da la impresión que tienes mal definido el `join`,  ¿No debería existir un `id` que relacione `inversion` y `gastos` más preciso que la `fecha`?

Comment: a ok ¿es que no se puede hacer el JOIN con fechas? es que yo deseo sumar los registros de cada tabla que correspondan a la misma fecha

Comment: para el caso de las fechas, lo puedes comparar en un `WHERE` por otro lado la idea del `JOIN` debería ser unir 2 tablas una con su llave primaria y la otra con la llave foránea que tiene o relaciona ambas

Comment: Claro que sí, pero el problema es que seguramente tienes varias filas con la misma fecha en ambas tablas, me da la impresión por lo que dices, que necesitas hacer las consultas por separado y luego si unirlas con un join

Comment: Una cosa que puedes hacer es agregar el `ID` (campo único)  al `GROUP BY`, por ejemplo: `GROUP BY (I.INVERSION_ID, I.FECHA)` suponiendo que el nombre de la columna sea `INVERSION_ID`. O bien los dos ids de cada tabla... depende de la estructura de datos que tengas.

Comment: al cambiar el  GROUP BY con el id si sale el registro que quiero pero sale dos veces el mismo registro.

Comment: Prueba con `GROUP BY (I.INVERSION_ID, G.GASTO_ID I.FECHA)` donde `GASTO_ID`  es la columna identificadora en la tabla `GASTOS`.  Si sigue sin funcionar da mas detalles sobre la estructura de tus tablas y ejemplos de los datos.

Comment: ya lo solucione es como el ejemplo que coloco  el Sr. Patricio Moracho en la respuesta que coloco aquí abajo, haciendo un doble select y luego cruzar las tablas,.

Comment: Pero marcaste como respuesta correcta la que no es de @PatricioMoracho, no te habrás confundido?

Comment: cierto, corregido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por lo que dices, necesitas sumar las filas de las dos tablas por fecha. Para esto, deberías en primer lugar agrupar por fecha cada tabla de forma independiente y luego sí unirlas mediante un `join`. Si haces el `join` directamente vas a duplicar filas en alguna o en ambas tablas, siempre que tengas más de una fila para una misma fecha en alguna de las dos tablas o en ambas.

Lo que te decía, sería algo así:

```
SELECT  I.FECHA,
        I.INVERSION_VALOR,
        G.GASTO_VALOR
        FROM (SELECT   FECHA,
                       SUM(VALOR) AS INVERSION_VALOR
                       FROM INVERSION
                       GROUP BY FECHA
              ) I
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT  FECHA,
                           SUM(VALOR) AS GASTO_VALOR 
                           FROM GASTOS
                           GROUP BY(FECHA)
              ) G
              ON G.FECHA = I.FECHA
```

Esto tiene un eventual problema, así como está la consulta te traerá todas las filas de `inversion` y solo las que coincidan con `gastos`. Esto se solucionaría fácilmente si mysql tuviera un `FULL OUTER JOIN`, lamentablemente no es así hay que emularlo de esta forma:

```
SELECT  I.FECHA,
        I.INVERSION_VALOR,
        G.GASTO_VALOR
        FROM (SELECT   FECHA,
                       SUM(VALOR) AS INVERSION_VALOR
                       FROM INVERSION
                       GROUP BY FECHA
              ) I
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT  FECHA,
                           SUM(VALOR) AS GASTO_VALOR 
                           FROM GASTOS
                           GROUP BY(FECHA)
              ) G
              ON G.FECHA = I.FECHA

UNION

SELECT  I.FECHA,
        I.INVERSION_VALOR,
        G.GASTO_VALOR
        FROM (SELECT   FECHA,
                       SUM(VALOR) AS INVERSION_VALOR
                       FROM INVERSION
                       GROUP BY FECHA
              ) I
        RIGHT JOIN (SELECT  FECHA,
                           SUM(VALOR) AS GASTO_VALOR 
                           FROM GASTOS
                           GROUP BY(FECHA)
              ) G
              ON G.FECHA = I.FECHA
        WHERE I.FECHA IS NULL
```

Si en alguna de las dos tablas no tuvieras filas ten en cuenta que obviamente las columnas de importes retornarán `null`, si prefieres mostrar el valor 0, deberías usar un `IFNULL(G.GASTO_VALOR, 0)` o `IFNULL(G.INVERSION_VALOR, 0)`

Comment: Gracias, Solucionado es así, haciendo el doble select y luego cruzando las tablas, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema quizá reside en que manejas Maestros y Detalles, al no utilizar de buena manera los join en las consultas de maestros detalle suele duplicarse el valor no quiere decir que este malo, mas bien que el valor se duplica por alguna variable que es distinta en el detalle que no lleva en el maestro.

```
SELECT I.FECHA      AS INV_FECHA,
       SUM(I.VALOR) AS INVERSION_VALOR, 
       SUM(G.VALOR) AS GASTO_VALOR 
       FROM INVERSION AS I 
       INNER JOIN GASTOS AS G ON I.FECHA = G.FECHA 
       GROUP BY(I.FECHA)`
```

Verifica los datos con un `Select * from *****` de tu tabla principal y de tu `Join` para encontrar el problema.